# Why is my CLI not running the index.js file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, command-line-interface

I am trying to build a CLI with node. Here is my package.json :

```json
{
  "name": "mycli",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "My CLI for stuff.",
  "main": "bin/index.js",
  "bin": {
    "mycli": "./bin/index.js"
  },
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "Nolan Knight",
  "license": "",
  "dependencies": {
    "boxen": "^7.1.0",
    "chalk": "^5.2.0",
    "yargs": "^17.7.2"
  }
}
```

Then, in the bin folder, I have index.js:

```js
import chalk from "chalk";
import boxen from "boxen";

const greeting = chalk.white.bold("Hello World This is the first Program!");
const boxenOptions = {
    padding: 1,
    margin: 1,
    borderStyle: "round",
    borderColor: "green",
    backgroundColor: "#555555"
};
const msgBox = boxen( greeting, boxenOptions );
console.log(msgBox);
```

I installed it globally, but when I run `mycli` it only opens index.js (after prompting me to select an app to open it in). When I run `node .` in my project it works, but I think for some reason the index.js file is not being run when I run `mycli`.

Comment: Did you reinstall it globally after you made the changes to `index.js`?

Comment: After running `npm install -g .` again, it still does not work. Also (I'll edit the question and put this in), when I run `mycli` in the terminal, it prompts me to select an app to open index.js in.

Comment: This might be due to the fact that Windows does not natively know how to handle a JavaScript file. You might have to specify a different command, to actually run the file, as simply using "mycli" might just trigger windows to open the file for editing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this issue, I had to right click on a javascript file in the Windows file explorer. Then, I selected open with and then clicked choose another app. From there, I navigated to where I had downloaded Node.js and selected it. This made Node the default js runner.

Answer (score 0):

1. add the shebang `#!/usr/bin/env node` on first line of index.js
2. empty line after the shebang may be needed
3. `run npm i -g` Again